# How to list hidden folder from apache directory with user access on xampp (Windows)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apache, htdocs

I put .htpasswd and .htaccess to one directory in htdocs. But when I want to see this folder on the index ?

What can I do to see this directory ?

In httpd.conf I put this lines:

```
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\meteo">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

This folder meteo have username and password access but is not visible of index..

Comment: .ht* files are hidden for a reason. Why should you want to expose those files that are designed to remain hidden?

Comment: I want to list all folders.. when user click on some access folder He need to write username and password, but I want to see the accessed folders..